# Carregar página via load()

Tags: jquery

Estou querendo fazer com que as minhas páginas sejam carregadas via load() do jquery, só que estou enfrentando um problema.

Eu tenho um menu com links numa página chamada menu.php eu estou querendo que quando eu clicar nos links do menu.php ele abra na mesma página (index.php) onde tenho um load(). O problema é que ele atualiza e redireciona para a página envez de abrir na mesma. Segue o meu código

**menu.php**

> ## Menu
>
> ```
>   <ul class="menu">
>
>       <li><a href="categoria/salada" class="linkmenu">SALADA</a></li>
>         <li><a href="categoria/arroz" class="linkmenu">ARROZ</a></li>
>         <li><a href="categoria/feijao" class="linkmenu">FEIJÃO</a></li>
>
>   </ul>
> ```

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu a").click(function( e ){
      e.preventDefault();
      var href = $( this ).attr('href');
      $("#content").load(href);
    });
  });
  </script>

<div id="content"></div>


<?php require("menu.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Sua biblioteca jQuery está bem desatualizada, já estamos na versão 1.11.1. Mas mesmo com este jQuery desatualizado, seu código parece estar rodando perfeitamente bem aqui.

Comment: Alisson, já tentou com o `return false;` no lugar do `e.preventDefault()` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer assim:

```
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery("body").on("click", "ul.menu a", function(){

        jQuery("#content").load( jQuery(this).attr('href') );

        return false;

    });

});
```